# How to make my MS SQL Server Query run faster?

Tags: sql-server

I have this kind of query in my ms sql.

```
SELECT 
    OdeaMainDataBase.dbo.ItemChoicesTable.*,
    CASE
       WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM StudentTestTablefromRemark 
                   WHERE StudID = @studId AND ExamID = @examId 
                     AND ItemBankID = @itemBankId 
                     AND ChoiceID = OdeaMainDataBase.dbo.ItemChoicesTable.ChoiceID) 
          THEN 'True' 
          ELSE 'False' 
    END AS isAnswered
FROM 
    OdeaMainDataBase.dbo.ItemChoicesTable
WHERE
    ItemBankID = @itemBankId
```

I observe that the `CASE` statement I made causes my query to run slow. When I remove that `CASE`, it run fast but I need that case for my output.

Here is the structure I want to display

**Item Choice Table**

```
ItemBankID   ChoiceID    ChoiceLetter
--------------------------------------
1            1           A
1            2           B
1            3           C
2            4           A
2            5           B
2            6           C
```

**Student Answers Table**

```
ItemBankID   ChoiceID    ChoiceLetter   StudentId
-------------------------------------------------
1            2           B              123
2            6           C              123
```

**Desired Output**

```
ItemBankID   ChoiceID    ChoiceLetter    IsAnswered
----------------------------------------------------
1            1           A               False
1            2           B               True
1            3           C               False
2            4           A               False
2            5           B               False
2            6           C               True
```

I want to achieve that output without slowing my program.

Any idea will do to me.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT i.*,
       CASE
         WHEN s.ChoiceID IS NULL THEN 'False'
         ELSE 'True'
       END
FROM   OdeaMainDataBase.dbo.ItemChoicesTable i
       LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentTestTablefromRemark s
                    ON s.ChoiceID = i.ChoiceID
                       AND s.ItemBankID = i.ItemBankID
                       AND s.StudID = @studId
                       AND s.ExamID = @examId
WHERE  i.ItemBankID = @itemBankId
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT OdeaMainDataBase.dbo.ItemChoicesTable.*,
ISNULL(a,'False') as isAnswered
FROM OdeaMainDataBase.dbo.ItemChoicesTable 
left outer join(Select 'True' as a,ChoiceID FROM StudentTestTablefromRemark 
Where StudID=@studId AND ExamID=@examId AND ItemBankID=@itemBankId )b on b.ChoiceID=OdeaMainDataBase.dbo.ItemChoicesTable.ChoiceID
Where ItemBankID = @itemBankId
```

Comment: Thank you for the response :)